# Unable to retrieve offset for a ASP.NET server-side control

Tags: javascript, offset, server-side-controls

I'm trying to retrieve the offsetHeight of a server-side control but it gives me an error. Here's the following code snippet -

```
  function Test() {
            var imgFavorite = $("<%= imgFavorite.ClientID %>"); //imgFavorite is a server-side asp:Image control.
            alert(imgFavorite); //[object Object]
            alert(imgFavorite.offsetHeight()); //undefined.    
   }
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the hash when declaring the jQuery object using an ID:

```
var imgFavorite = $("#<%= imgFavorite.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely missed it!